# Ordered Fields and the Completeness Axiom

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, ordered-fields

I have the following problem that I am stuck on:

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an ordered field with the property that if $[a,b]$ is any closed interval and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{F}$ is any continuous function such that $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$, then there is an $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x)=0$. Show that such a field $\mathbb{F}$ has the least upper bound property.

*My Strategy/Thoughts*: Am I correct in thinking that this is just showing that the Intermediate Value Theorem implies the Completeness Axiom? If so, how do I go about it? I was thinking that I could assume that the Intermediate Value Theorem holds for some $f$ on the field, and assume that the Completeness Axiom does not necessarily hold. Then I think I could reach a contradiction by constructing a function $f$ which is not continuous. Would that work?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $F$ with an upper bound, but with no least upper bound. Let $B$ be the set of upper bounds of $A$. Investigate
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1&x\in B,\\
1&x\notin B.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I figured it would be something like this. I'll try it out!